# access vba runtime error 2467 while hiding the table programatically

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to hide one of the access table or querytable with vba code, it is throwing run time error " expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesnt exist"

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Application.SetHiddenAttribute acQuery, samplesql, False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetHiddenAttribute` expects a string value for its *ObjectName* parameter.  So if *samplesql* is the name of a saved query, include that name in quotes.

```
Application.SetHiddenAttribute acQuery, "samplesql", False
```